# Page curl animation not shown fullscreen in case of facing pages mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, page-curl

I am refering to Ole Begemann's API for Page Curl which has facing pages in the Landscape mode.

Here is the link I am refering to:

https://github.com/ole/leaves/tree/twopages

Now the problem is even if my images are 768 X 1024 or 1024 X 768 Pixels, it still shows only a small image and rest of the page show white background.

I want to make the image full screen in terms of height. How can I remove the white space shown in the screenshot?

Here is a screen shot of how it looks. this screen shot has same images on both the facing pages, only thing is the height of the image should be 768.0 pixels:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it done.

The image was drawn proportionally so there was a fixed proportion between height and width.

I removed that and ran it and it is working now.

Hope this helps someone.

If anyone is imlpementing the same API and having any problems with that, then please leave a comment below.. I will be happy to help.